# HTML5 drag and drop with button and td

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag a button and drop it on to a td and it does not seem to be working. The dragging is easy. But I can't seem to be able to set up the td to accept the drop. Here is the [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/t5LPj/2/)

I have looked at the documentation on [some](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/) [excellent](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_Operations) [articles](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop) but still can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JQueryUI to implement drag-and-drop easily:

JQueryUI: [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) & [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)

Comment: Thanks but I'm hoping to use native HTML5 elements. (It should work if it's supported, dammit!! :-) If I can't figure out how to make it work, I'll use a library.

Comment: Having gone through these insane browser irregularities across platforms, and [this rant](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html), I believe DaneSoul has the right answer. It's not what I wanted but is what I needed.

Comment: Good link tinkerr! Funny stuff and I know now to steer well clear of HTML5 drag and drop.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like a problem with the alert calls in your `dragenter` handler. I've updated the debug statements in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38pcN/1/) to use `console.log` instead of `alert` which seems to result in the expected behaviour in the latest version of Chrome.

`console.log` is a much better choice for outputting debug statements than the `alert` method, not least because it's far less intrusive. If you're concerned about errors in browsers which do not support the console, there's a shiv included in the [HTML5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) which you should probably consider using.

In terms of cross-browser support, my advice would be to check that drag and drop is fully supported in all the browsers you hope to support. [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/dragndrop) is an excellent resource for such a check, although you could alternatively test one of the demos you link to in each of your target browsers. If not, then you should take DaneSoul's advice and consider jQueryUI which is designed to paper over these frustrating gaps and idiosyncrasies in support for certain features.

Comment: Thanks. Your fiddle works in Chrome/Windows but not on Chrome/Mac. Any idea how to make your fiddle work on all platforms? PS - You removed the alert from the dragenter handler. The drop handler is still using an alert. I didn't see any console logging so perhaps you sent the wrong link?

Comment: Sorry, obviously didn't save the changes to my fiddle. Try the updated link in the answer and let me know if it fixes it in Mac.

Comment: Works in Chrome/Win7, Safari/Mac. Does not work on Chrome/Mac or any Firefox. On Safari/Windows, the dragEnter works but not the drop. This is crazy. And interestingly, the dragEnter log fires several times. It should fire only once.

Comment: I'm not in a position to test on a Mac unfortunately but have updated my answer with some further suggestions.

Comment: You're right. I have upvoted your response but accepted DaneSoul's as the answer.